# Rails: send_file not causing download, links to 'show' controller method instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download

First time using rails, I'm trying to create a download link to get something off the file system.

In my view, I've got

```
<%= link_to 'Show', upload, :method => :download %>
```

and my 'download' method in my controller looks like:

```
def download
   @upload = Upload.find(params[:id])
   send_file '/data_store/50692.pdf'
```

This is needed because I have restrictions on who can view this pdf, but on this page, I get linked to

```
http://localhost:3000/uploads/10
```

(10 is the id of this 'upload')

and on that page, I get the error

```
    Unknown action

No action responded to 10. Actions: clearance, create, destroy, download, edit, index, is_admin, new, show, su_required, and update
```

I want it instead to stay on the same page, and offer the user a download prompt, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a problem in the calling download method.

Try this one

```
<%= link_to "Show",:controller=>'controllername',:action=>'download',:id=>upload.id %>
```

You must pass your controller name in the place "controllername".

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should be looking into a Ajax call if you'd want to stay on the same page and offer the user a download prompt, but the code given below would also work. Upon clicking the "download" link it'll open a new tab/window,offer the user a download prompt and close the tab/window.

Also the `:method` parameter to `link_to` tells it which HTTP method (POST,GET,DELETE,PUT) to use. To reference the "download" method in your controller use the `:action` parameter.

```
view
----
<%= link_to 'Show', upload, :action => :download, {:target => "_blank"} %>      

controller
----------
return send_file '/data_store/50692.pdf', :type => "application/pdf", :filename => "50692.pdf"
```